# Can scenes taking place right after each other in the same place have separate headers?

Tags: formatting, screenwriting, scene, script, conventions

I'm writing a screenplay and in it there are two different scenes that take place in the same place and with one immediately after the other both chronologically and in the script. I want to separate out the scenes because they serve different story and dramatic functions, but it might look weird considering the scene headers would be the exact same. Is there precedence for identical scene headers right beside each other in a script?

**Example:**

```
INT. DOCK - CONTINUOUS
<First scene>

INT. DOCK - CONTINUOUS
<Second scene>
```

Answer (score 2):

dramatic function doesn't define the heading. As long as the time and location are the same you stay within that set heading. If it is later on in the day in the same location and time such as day or night then slug line "LATER".